# Multiple tables with different columns on single BIRT reports

Tags: export-to-csv, delimiter, birt, import-from-excel, ssconvert

I have a BIRT report with multiple tables with different datasets and number of columns on it. I generate output in .xls and convert into .csv using `ssconvert` utility on Unix. But in the .csv file I see extra delimiter for tables where there are fewer columns. For example, here is the .csv output with extra "," in .csv file:

table1-- this has only 10 columns
5912,,,0,,,0,,0,,,0,,,0,,,0,,,

tables2 --this has 20 columns
'12619493',28/03/2018 17:27:40,sdfsdfasd,'61901492478'1.08,,,1.08,sdfs,,dsf,,sdfadfs,'738331',,434,,,,,,,333,

I try to put grid but still I see extra ",". I have opened the .xls file and I see it has same issue. The cells in Excel are merged.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with BIRT.

Comment: if i keep single table in birt then there is no extra ',' in csv file.

Comment: If i open the xls file created by birt then i see the table columns are shifted in worksheets in multiple table senario.